# how to validate Edit to only numbers & only text in inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

Is there a way to limit the characters to numbers and lenght to 10 with no space and another edit for just ?
its for a phone number, and name that needs to have no spaces, dont have an idea how to do it. Found a code that try some ways to implement but dont work
here is what I found for dont allow letters.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key in ['a'..'z']) or (Key in ['A'..'Z'])  then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Here for dont allow numbers:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key in ['0'..'9'] then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

and this for no space:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if key = Char(VK_SPACE) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

can implement something similar in inno?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit MaxLength property of Edit1 to limit character

```
Edit1.MaxLength:=10;
```

Comment: `TEdit` has no **Caption** property :) use **Text** property ! `copy(...)` is not needed : use `key := #0` instead

Comment: I think **Text** property and **Caption** property are equivalent. I did not know `key:=#0` in **KeyPress** event, thank you

Comment: **Also take care :** At the monent you are inside `Edit1KeyPress()` event. That means `Edit1.Text` is not altered at the moment you do copy(...) !!! with a remove of the last char you remove a valid char. Not setting `Key := 0;` you now added a number behind last killed char : START : **abcd** removed `d` and added e.g. 5 Result in Edit1.Text = **abc5** . Please improve your answer or delete them.

Comment: This answer is for Delphi, while the question is about Inno setup. So this is all completely irrelevant.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : I agree ! Only `Edit1.MaxLength:=10;` is correct.